# How do I read json child node in c#

Tags: c#, json, get

I have this code that reads json. It works fine, but I cant figure out how to read the child node `Name` under `caller`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://**url**");
        myReq.Method = "GET";
        myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization: Basic **Authkey**");

        WebResponse response = myReq.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);

        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();

        List<Incident> Incidents = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Incident>>(json);

        foreach (Incident inc in Incidents)
        {
            LTInc.Text += inc.number + "</br>" + inc.briefDescription  + "</br>" + inc.dynamicName + "</br></br>";
        }          
    }

    public class Incident
    {
        public string number;
        public string briefDescription;
        public string request;
        //public IList<string> caller;
        public string dynamicName;
    }
}
```

The Json string looks somthing like this:

```
"number": "S 1901-079",
"request": "reg****",
"briefDescription": "sfdgfgfgfgfg",
"Caller":{
   "ID": "1",
   "Name": "TestName"
```

Comment: As you can see caller is list of strings. There are two solutions 1 deserialize Caller into object and read property Name or you can search through string for string "Name" and get the value you want. IMO deserialization would be better approach(C# and stuff :))

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
public class Incident
{
    public string number;
    public string briefDescription;
    public string request;
    public IList<Caller> caller;
    public string dynamicName;
}

public class Caller
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
```

But: you should use properties instead of fields, and I suggets you switch to `HttpClient`.

Two readings you should check:

- https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/
- http://byterot.blogspot.com/2012/06/asp-net-web-api-mediatypeformatter.html

Comment: The second class should be `Caller`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your class to look like:

```
public class Incident
{
   public string Number { get; set; }
   public string Request { get; set; }
   public string BriefDescription { get; set; }
   public List<Caller> Caller { get; set; }
}
```

And introduce a new class called `Caller` as:

```
public class Caller
{
   public string ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```